# One Textview overlaps another in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have ConstraintLayout with two TextView inside:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to place the first one at the top left-corner of parent container and to place the second one at the top-right parent's corner. But both textviews can have text with any length. And when first one has very long text it overlaps the second textview. I can solve this problem by wrapping both textviews in LinearLayout. But this way seems to me inelegant. Maybe there is another way to do it? I mean with ConstraintLayout's feautures

Comment: You can use relative layout instead

Comment: You need horizontal chain and width with `0dp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remove the `wrap_content` from your widths as this makes the left/right constraints irrelevant. Use `0dp` in its place to make it adhere to the constraints' rules.

Then create a horizontal chain between the views and have it as `spread`, so that the views don’t overlap at any point and they also stay at the edges of the screen at all times.

Finally, align the texts accordingly so that the left one aligns to the start of the view and the right one aligns to the end. In the example below you see that no matter how long the text is, the views don’t overlap and stick to their sides.

**NOTE:** It is considered better practice to use start/end constraints (as in my code) instead of left/right in order to cater for devices with different text direction. You can also modify the code below by adding the appropriate margins to have the text farther away from the edges of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: JIC this helps some else but using left/right over start/end constraints can give different results. Switching to start/end resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chauhan"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mehul"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This way second TextView won't overlap first one for sure, but there might happen that first is too long so that there is no place for second one. If that could be the case I would recommend setting maxWidth to first TextView, so that in worst case scenario there is some space left for second TextView.

Also I added graviti to second one to keep text on right side of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/second"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvSecond"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFirst"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```